# How to know when job from viewModel is done

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, jobs

I am trying to figure out how jobs with coroutines work. Basically, I want to launch this coroutine from `FirstFragment` and after that navigate to `SecondFragment` and get notified when this job is done. I call `getData()` in `FirstFragment` `onViewCreated()` and navigate to `SecondFragment`. Whether I write `getData().isCompleted` or `getData().invokeOnCompletion {  }` in `SecondFragment` nothing happens. I don't know if I am missing something or not starting job correctly or something else.

```
private val _data = MutableStateFlow<GetResource<String>?>(null)
val data: StateFlow<GetResource<String>?> = _data

fun getData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.getData().collect {
        _data.value = it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Flow from a database never completes because it is supposed to monitor the database for changes indefinitely. It only stops when the coroutine is cancelled. Therefore the Job that collects such a Flow will never complete. Also, if you call `getData()` on the repo again, you are getting a new Flow instance each time.

Regardless of what you're doing, you need to be sure you are using the same ViewModel instance between both fragments by scoping it to the Activity. (Use `by activityViewModels()` for example.) This is so the `viewModelScope` won't be cancelled during the transition between Fragments.

If all you need is a single item from the repo one time, probably the simplest thing to do would be to expose a suspend function from the repo instead of a Flow. Then turn it into a Deferred. Maybe by making it a `Lazy`, you can selectively decide when to start retrieving the value. Omit the `lazy` if you just want to start retrieving the value immediately when the first Fragment starts.

```
// In the shared view model:
val data: Deferred<GetResource<String>> by lazy { 
    viewModelScope.async {
      repository.getData() // suspend function returning GetResource<String>
    }
  }

fun startDataRetrieval() { data } // access the lazy property to start its coroutine

// In second fragment:
lifecycleScope.launch {
  val value = mySharedViewModel.data.await()
  // do something with value
}
```

But if you have to have the Flow because you’re using it for other purposes:

If you just want the first available value from the Flow, have the second Fragment monitor your `data` StateFlow for its first valid value.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  val value = mySharedViewModel.data.filterNotNull().first()
  // do something with first arrived value
}
```

And you can use SharedFlow so you don’t have to make the data type nullable. If you do this you can omit `filterNotNull()` above. In your ViewModel, it’s easier to do this with `shareIn` than your code that has to use a backing property and manually collect the source.

```
val data: SharedFlow<GetResource<String>> = repository.getData()
  .shareIn(viewModelScope, replay = 1, SharingStarted.Eagerly)
```

If you need to wait before starting the collection to the SharedFlow, then you could make the property lazy.

Comment: you said ``(Use by activityViewModels() for example.) This is so the viewModelScope won't be cancelled during the transition between Activities``  _during the transition between __Activities__?_ I think it should be __Fragments__

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Tenfour04 's answer, I would like to contribute a little more.
If you really want to control over the jobs or [Structured Concurrency](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/), i would suggest use custom way of handling the coroutine rather than coupled your code with the `viewModelScope`.
There are couple of things you need to make sure:
1- What happen when cancellation or exception occurrs
2- you have to manage the lifecycle of the coroutine(CoroutineScope)
3- Cancelling scope, depends on usecase like problem facing you are right now
4- Scope of ViewModel e.g: Either it is tied to activity(Shared ViewModel) or for specific fragment.
If you are not handling either of these carefully specifically first 3, your are more likely to leaking the coroutine your are gurenteed gonna get misbehavior of you app.
**Whenever you start any coroutine in Custom way you have to make sure, what is going to be the lifecycle, when it gonna end, This is so important, it can cause real problems**

Luckily, i have this sample of CustomViewModel using Jobs: [Structured Concurrency sample code](https://github.com/MuhammadUnderScoreUsman/StructuredConcurrency--KotlinCoroutines/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mohammadosman/structuredconcurrency_kotlincoroutines/presentation/MainViewModel.kt)

Comment: Your example publicly exposes the ViewModel itself as a CoroutineScope, so it doesn't make sense for `cancelScope()` to be `internal`. I think it should also cancel itself when destroyed because the outside Fragments can't easily know when the ViewModel is going out of scope and cancel them from the outside. I think it would be cleanest for any custom scope to be a private member rather than making the outside classes responsible for managing the scope lifecycle.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right, but you are wrong about this repository, i didn't made that sample only for cancellation scope. I was building custom viewModel without using Actual ViewModel(). and about cancelScope(), it is being cancelled in onDestroy() from Activity.

Comment: What I mean is, `internal fun cancelScope()` is redundant to the public `fun cancel()` that you are exposing by having the ViewModel implement CoroutineScope.